# Finding non overlapping squares?

Tags: graph-theory

This type of problem is really tricky for me to make heads and tails of.
I have a graph in form of a mesh that looks like below.

```
  A-----B-----C-----D
  |     |     |     |
  E-----F-----G-----H
  |     |     |     |
  I-----J-----K-----L
  |     |     |     |
  M-----N-----O-----P
```

now, that's a valid graph and if I'm asked what the number of squares are,  I'm supposed to count unit squares and answer 9.

```
  A-----B-----C-----D
  |     |           |
  E-----F     G     H
  |                 |
  I     J     K     L
  |                 |
  M-----N-----O-----P
```

That's an invalid graph as it contains one 1x1 square overlapping with one 3x3 square. In this case, it's overlapping in a corner but generally, it can be FGJK or BFJKLHDC. those are invalid as well.

My question is, how can I validate the graph for being with non overlapping squares and next, how do I count the squares in a valid graph?

Also, no dangling edges, each edge must be a part of a square.

My approach so far:
1. Finding largest possible square with given edge. Size M
2. Finding smallest possible square with given edge. Size N. 
3. Check if N is a factor of M and Check if M square is fully tiled with N squares.

Area where I'm stuck:
I'm unable to create the algorithm using dynamic programming.  The algorithm I created is O(n^6) which I'm too ashamed to post here.

Area of application:
Object resonance. Please kindly don't ask the original problem as I'm not at liberty to speak about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, how can I validate the graph for being with non overlapping squares and next, how do I count the squares in a valid graph?

I understand this as follows :

1. Check if the graph has a square partition
2. If yes, count the number of squares in the partition

Let `n` be the number of vertices of the side of the grid. In you case (n = 4), there are exactly 3 valid configurations (up to symmetries) :

```
A-----B-----C-----D        A-----B-----C-----D        A-----B-----C-----D
|     |     |     |        |     |     |     |        |                 |
E-----F-----G-----H        E-----F-----G-----H        E     F     G     H
|     |     |     |        |     |           |        |                 |
I-----J-----K-----L        I-----J     K     L        I     J     K     L
|     |     |     |        |     |           |        |                 |
M-----N-----O-----P        M-----N-----O-----P        M-----N-----O-----P
```

The approach I suggest for the first question is the following : First, assign a number to each tile like this :

```
A-----B-----C-----D
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
E-----F-----G-----H
|  4  |  5  |  6  |
I-----J-----K-----L
|  7  |  8  |  9  | 
M-----N-----O-----P
```

Then create sets of tiles that belong to the same partition. For example in the second configuration (with one square of side 2 and 5 squares of side 1), you would have the 6 following sets : `{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5, 6, 8, 9}, {7}`. Now comes the validation :

- sets of size `1` are automatically validated
- sets of size `4` must be of the form `{k}, {k+1}, {k+n-1}, {k+n}` for some `k`
- more generally, sets of size `S^2` must be of the form `{ k+i+(n-1)j | 0<=i<S, 0<=j<S }` for some `k`

This validation step can actually be done as you parse the tiles is ascending order and mark them when processed : the next unmarked tile `k` has to be the top left-hand corner of a square : check that the tiles connected to `k` form a set as described in the validation criteria above (tile connection is checked by looking for the absence of an edge between consecutive tiles). This way, if you find that a partition is not a square, then you can abort the program.

If all the partitions are validated, then the number of squares is simply the number of sets you found (in the example case it would be 6).

One last thing is the "dangling edge" problem : simply check that all vertices have degree at least `2`. This can be done at the beginning of the algo, or it may not be necessary depending on how you write the "square validation" procedure.

The overall time complexity of this program looks to be `O(n^2)`, where `n` is the side of your grid, so it is actually linear in the order of the graph (number of vertices). When you mention a complexity of `O(n^6)`, I am not sure what `n` is though.